# Detect UIImageView click in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, imageview

I have to make a call to specific number when imageview is clicked in tableviewcell.The number to which call is made is displayed in a label beside the imageview.But I couldn't get which cell is clicked.Always its referring to the last cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        lblphone = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        lblphone.tag = 116;
        lblphone.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [lblphone setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
        [lblphone setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        [lblphone setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelButton:)];
        tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView=NO;
        [tapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
        [lblphone addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
        [tapGestureRecognizer release];
        [cell addSubview:lblphone];

        myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        myImageView.tag = 120;
        myImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"CallImg.png"];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageSelectedInTable:)];
        [tapped setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
        [myImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
        [tapped release];
        [cell addSubview:myImageView];
    }

    [myImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50,30,30)];
    myImageView= (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:120];
    myImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"CallImg.png"];
    myImageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    CGSize constraint5 = CGSizeMake(320, 2000.0f);
    CGSize size5=[phone sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14] constrainedToSize:constraint5 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    lblphone =(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:116];
    [lblphone setFrame:CGRectMake(45,name.frame.size.height+name.frame.origin.y,320, size5.height)];
    lblphone.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
    lblphone.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    lblphone.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",phone ];
    [lblphone sizeToFit];
}
```

And in the tapgesture of imageclick I am writing this :

```
-(IBAction)imageSelectedInTable:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *) [gesture view];
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[[imgView superview]superview];
    NSIndexPath *tappedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"Image Tap %@", tappedIndexPath);
    UILabel *phoneno = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:116];

    NSString *phoneNumber = [@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:phoneno.text];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
}
```

But it  is always  referncing to the last cell clicked irrespective of which cell is clicked.Couldn't understand where im going wrong ?

Comment: Make a custom button on your imageView and find the index path through touch methods so no need to used UITapGestureRecognizer in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you try to access your cell,

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[[imgView superview]superview];
```

but you add your image view to

```
[cell addSubview:myImageView];
```

You should be adding your image view to `cell.contentView`.

Comment: It is a very viable alternative to use tags to store row index as @iPatel suggested. There are two clear disadvantages to that however you need to consider. 1) You cannot use it in tableview that has sections. 2) You give up ability to use tags to access different UI elements inside cell's contentView.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the image view is a subview of the cell (one step down the tree), and the code that's probing for the parent is taking two steps up ...superview superview.  (That latter approach is right for nib defined cells which add subviews to the cell's contentView).

Here's a safer way to climb the view hierarchy that will work no matter how the cell was built.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableViewCellContaining:(UIView *)aView {

    UIView *answer = aView;
    while (answer && ![answer isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell self]])
        answer = answer.superview;
    return answer;
}
```

I think your code will probably work if you replace this line:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[[imgView superview]superview];
```

with this line

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableViewCellContaining:imgView]
```

Answer (score 1):

for get/know Which cell is clicked, Write Following code

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[imgView superview]superview];
```

and if you alSo want to get `indexPath` of tapped cell then write

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

**EDITED :-> Another way is**

Give `tag` of `UIImageView` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` Method 
Such like,

```
imageView.tag = indexPath.row;
```

And Use Following Code

```
int row = ((UIImageView*)imgView).tag; //Or// int row = ((UIGestureRecognizer *)sender).view.tag;

NSIndexPath* indexpath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0]; 
UITableViewCell* cell = [table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Here You can get `Cell` of Tapped `UIImageView`.

Comment: But NSIndexpath is getting null in my case .What can I do ?

Comment: But I have written it already in my code.Sorry can u tell me whats the difference I wrote and ur code?

Comment: @Aaradhya-wt happening ?? ma code is work ?? or Not ?? reply me :)

Comment: @iPatel  Yes its working now.Thanks for ur help but sorry I couldn't accept it as answer as the code for which I have marked as answer is more nearer to the code which I wrote(I need to change only a single line).I will upvote ur answer.Thanks iPatel.....

Comment: Yes, this is a good suggestion @iPatel. Using tags to identify row number was my first thought, but I saw that tags were already used and I was assuming tags were used to access different views inside tableview cell.